# How to disable debugger in chrome

Tags: web

When I test my web page. [image: This is the messge I got.]

This error message I got.After this messge, I am not able to proceed with my web page.
Can you explain me how to rectify from this?

Comment: Search for "debugger" in your code and remove it, BTW this is not an error message.

Comment: yes ,its not a error message. But I got this "Paused in debugger"

Comment: Or in your chrome developper tools, in the `sources` tab, uncheck the `pause on exceptions` toggle (light pause sign in a dark stop sign) on the right debugger panel

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6fKze.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because u have kept the break point in your source scripts.If you want to ignore this just close the `Console window` or simply press `f8`